# What is new Number(122) in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I saw a question here -> https://github.com/lydiahallie/javascript-questions#answer-c-1

Consider the below code snippet.

```js
let a = 3;
let b = Number(3)
let c = new Number(3)

a == b // true
a === b // true
// but
a===c or b === c // false
```

The situation is also explained in the above repo, but I would like to know what are the other features of this `c` object.

I also tried to see its properties or methods in the browser console, and I found that it is the same as a, the methods are `toFixed, etc`.

Comment: What is the problem ? with the new operator you create a new object based on a prototype, or if you prefer you "clone" the entire Number object. READ the doc! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`new Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number) creates a wrapper object.

To get its primitive value, you can use [`Number#valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/valueOf):

```js
let a = 3, b = Number(3), c = new Number(3);

console.log(typeof c);

console.log(a === c.valueOf());
console.log(b === c.valueOf());
```

Answer (score 1):

Because

```js
let a = 3; // is a number
let b = Number(3) // is a number
let c = new Number(3) // is an object

a == b // true
a === b // true
// but
a===c or b === c // false
```

Is that clear?

Comment: I  already said that `The situation is also explained in the above repo` -> [here](https://github.com/lydiahallie/javascript-questions#answer-c-1) it is clearly stated that new Number() is an object. But, I am interested in other features of this object. The answer I found is that, new Number() will create create a Object wrapper around the native Integer type just like Java wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

When you check the `typeof` all the values then you will get

`typeof a` => `number`

`typeof b` => `number`

`typeof c` => `object`

`===` is `strict equality`, so it will check its `type` and `value`

**1)** If you want to check equality either you can use `a == c` and `b == c` .

**2)** use the `valueOf` method of `c` and compare it with `a` and `b` as:

```
a === c.valueOf();
b === c.valueOf();
```

```js
let a = 3;
let b = Number(3);
let c = new Number(3);

console.log(typeof a === "number"); // true
console.log(typeof b === "number"); // true
console.log(typeof c === "number"); // false
console.log(typeof c === "object"); // true

console.log(a == c);
console.log(b == c);
console.log(a === c);
console.log(b === c);

console.log(a === c.valueOf());
console.log(b === c.valueOf());
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```